# How to allow anonymous information sharing and uploading?

Tags: language-agnostic, web, uploading

I am interested in building a website that allows users to be fully anonymous. Information they share or upload should not be traceable back to the user. What measures need to be taken in order to ensure a user's anonymity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might investigate previous systems that try to support anonymity or psedudonymity or both.
Perhaps you could use those systems to give improved anonymity or psedudonymity.
Even if you don't use those systems, perhaps you can apply ideas and perhaps even source code developed for these systems to your system.

- [the onion router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) (TOR) anonymous network has some interesting ideas for preserving anonymity. Perhaps your website could reject connections that *dont* go though such an anonymizing network?
- [Freenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenet)
- [invisible internet project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P) (I2P)
- [Osiris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris_%28Serverless_Portal_System%29) Serverless Portal System
- [anonymous P2P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/anonymous_P2P) applications